# Does afnetworking support web socket handling?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Do we have facility for working with WebSockets in AFNetworking for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately AFNetworking doesn't support websocket handling, I am using [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) for websocket handling.

Comment: I too found so on the internet.. Just wanted to confirm.. Thanks!